# Printing a java scriptlet variable as if it is a JavaScript variable

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

hello i need to output a java variable inside a javascript call inside a tag inside a jsp !

for example:

```
 <% String param = "hello";%>

<dmf:checkbox  name="checkbox"
  onclick = "selectAll(<%=param%>)"
/>
```

the javascript generated is:

`selectAll(<%=param%>),this);` but I actually want something like

```
selectAllCheckBoxes(Hello),this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not escaping. That's just printing a scriptlet variable as if it is a JavaScript variable.

Besides, your examples are confusing, they doesn't match each other and the Javascript code is syntactically invalid. I can at least tell that JavaScript string variables are to be surrounded by quotes. If you want to end up with

```
selectAllCheckBoxes('Hello', this);
```

where `Hello` should be obtained as a value of the scriptlet local `name` variable (the `param` is a reserved variable name, you shouldn't use it yourself), then you need to do

```
selectAllCheckBoxes('<%= name %>', this);
```

In the same way, if you want to end up with

```
onclick="selectAll('Hello')"
```

you need to do

```
onclick="selectAll('<%= name %>')"
```

That said, I strongly recommend you to stop using the old fashioned scriptlets which are been discouraged since more than a decade. JSP programmers were been recommended to use taglibs and EL only to make the JSP code more clean and robust and better maintainable. You can use taglibs such as [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) to control the flow in the JSP page and you can use [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) to access the "back-end" data. Your example can be replaced by:

```
<c:set var="name" value="Hello" />

...

selectAllCheckBoxes('${name}', this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate the whole attribute value with a scriptlet, like this:

```
<dmf:checkbox  name="checkbox"
   onclick = "<%= "selectAll(" + param + ")" %>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are trying to achieve this?

```
var myVar = '<%= (String)request.getParameter("tab") %>'; 
loadtabs(myVar);
```